# How to display 12 Bit And 16 Bits (Dicom) images in UIImageView

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Just I want t display 12 bit or 16 bits of Images In UIImageView But Images are not displayed properly so please suggest me some solution I am struggling from few day for display these images

for more information please check this [Link](http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/How-to-display-12-bit-images-in-UIImageView-td4656427.html) which has code and images. The code is reproduced here:

```
const int bytesPerPixel = 4; 
int _width = (int)_drawArg.RectUIImageMatrix.Width; 
int _height = (int)_drawArg.RectUIImageMatrix.Height; 
CGImage _bitmap ; 

Rectangle srcRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, imageGraphic.Columns, imageGraphic.Rows); 
Rectangle rect = Rectangle.Round(new RectangleF(0,0,_width , _height)); 
Rectangle dstRectangle = rect; 

int[] srcPixels = new int[image.Columns * image.Rows * image.PixelData.BytesPerPixel]; 

int bitsPerComponent = 8; 
int bytesPerRow = srcRectangle.Width * bytesPerPixel  *2; 
var  pixelBytes = imageGraphic.PixelData.Raw; 
CGColorSpace _color = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB(); 
CGDataProvider _provide = new CGDataProvider(pixelBytes , 0,pixelBytes.Length); 

_bitmap = new CGImage(srcRectangle.Width,srcRectangle.Height ,bitsPerComponent,32,bytesPerRow , _color , CGBitmapFlags.ByteOrder16Big | CGBitmapFlags.PremultipliedLast ,_provide ,null ,true ,CGColorRenderingIntent.Default); 

ImgView.Image = UIImage.FromImage(_bitmap);
```

There

thnks for help in advc

Comment: So, this code is what, C++? It would be nice to know. Also, you gave us no info on "image" and its properties. Without knowing what the source format is, its impossible to help you at all. You are telling CGImageRef that the data in pixelBytes is 32 bits, big endian, and alpha last. Somehow I don't think this is try.

Comment: from the link you posted it seems that the problem you're experiencing is, that the resolution is wrong - the images seems wider than it should - is this correct? Where do your parameters for new CGImage come from? have you tried to recalculate the width of your image?

Comment: Also, try googling "convert DICOM to UIImage" - you will get many hits on this site. This is a difficult task with many variations - good luck.

Comment: Yes Gambrinus Image size is much more greater than UIImageView for Example Image Width = 2500 and Height = 2048 and UIImageView Height = 759 and Width = 748 also One thing i have to ask parameter that I pass to CGImage such Height and Width that should be a Image height & width or UIImageView Height and Width